# session value is not accessible in another page when admin is logged out in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I am getting issue in wordpress session where I am setting up the
session value on ajax request and the value is initialized as it
required but when I try to check this value after refreshing the
current tab. This value is reset. I observed two things in that:

1. If I try to fetch session value on the same page it is accessible
   but in case of another page it is not accessible.
2. If the admin is logged in into wp then everything is working fine. I
   am getting the value as I required.

I also used to try this code on another wordpress and it works fine.
Please let me know if there is any issue  related to the permissions
or anything else.

Comment: Make sure there is no whitespace in your config files or files you've updated (It's usually a blank line before the <?php or after the ?> at the end.)

Comment: You added session_start();

Answer (score 0):

Basically WordPress not make use of sessions, $_SESSION is one of the global variables which are unset by the WordPress. So, basically you have to declare session explicitly.

If you are using PHP `5.4>`

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    echo 'Session is active';
}
```

1. `PHP_SESSION_DISABLED` if sessions are disabled.
2. `PHP_SESSION_NONE` if sessions are enabled, but none exists.
3. `PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE` if sessions are enabled, and one exists.

Moreover, I will suggest to use as following (Paste this function in functions.php)::

```
function _mySessionSet()
{
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
        echo 'Session is active';
    }
}
add_action('init', '_mySessionSet');
```

I am using same way to initialise `session's` in our `WP` website.

Comment: I have tried with the way you suggested. but still its not work for me. Actually I am creating session on dropdown onchange event in php during ajax request and it creating fine. But Once its created then it should be sustain even after the page refresh.I am checking the session value like print_r($_SESSION). But not getting the selected value in session. Also I have to delete the session value when browser is closed. This is not seems to be possible through cookie thats why i used session instead. And in my another wordpress setup this all working fine.Please suggest me out of this.
Thanks

Comment: **I am using php version 5.5.38 **

Comment: As, I mentioned before WordPress unset the `$_SESSION` variable on its own. Therefore, we need to start the session whenever a page refreshed. Please, let me know how you are using function shared above in your WordPress setup.